# Symfony list assets bundles and make new one

Tags: symfony, assets

One of most asked questions and I didn't find answer.

1. How to list existed assets bundles.
2. How to make new assets bundle.

I had tried with

```
 php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

and

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink
```

In project I work currently, there is 4 bundles and using suggested /web folder for assets is not in option.
Also I had tried

```
asset('@Bundle/Resources/public/images/image.png')
```

I must notice that this `'@Bundle/Resources/public/...'` worked for calling assets in block

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% stylesheets
    '@Bundle/Resources/public/css/some.css'
    filter='cssrewrite' output='css/compiled.app.css'
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

but when tried `"asset('...')"` I got error undefined assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just study this:

**http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html**

and solve problem with images using symfony image tag

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

**Also assets bundles is founding in**  `web/bundles` **folder after executing command** `assets:install --symlink`

and there you can see lowercase asset bundle name in example `AppTestBundle` **will be just** `apptest`